# equation of line passing through origin perpendicular to plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Plane equation P: 4x + 4y -5z = 14.
Find a vector equation, parametric equations, and Cartesian equations for the line L that passes through the origin and is perpendicular to the plane P.

Can someone point me in the right direction or maybe explain how I should go about solving this question? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that your plane *equation* is missing an equals sign

Comment: thanks for letting me know!

Comment: You're welcome; I see that now you have edited and addressed that

Answer (score 1):

The direction vector of the line is the normal vector to the plane which is $<4,4,-5>$

Thus you get $$x=4t, y=4t,z=-5t$$ for parametric and $$x/4=y/4=z/{-5}$$ for canonical form of the line.

Answer (score 1):

A normal vector to the plane is $(4,4,-5).$ Thus, a line passing through the point $(0,0,0)$ in the direction of this normal vector is given by $$(0,0,0)+t(4,4,-5)=(x,y,z),$$ where $t$ is an arbitrary real number and $(x,y,z)$ is any point in this line. This is the required parametric form. Can you now find the other forms?

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the line is given by
$$\vec{x}=t[a_x,a_y,a_z]$$ and it must be $$[a_x,a_y,a_z]=s[4,4,-5]$$ where $s,t$ are real numbers.